# Flutter Accessibility - Lost focus after Getx modal dialog has been closed

Tags: flutter, accessibility, flutter-getx

We are trying to make our application accessible with screen readers for visually impaired people.

One problem is, that after a modal dialog like Get.bottomSheet() was closed, the focus goes back to the top of our page. For blind people this behaviour is very heavy to get along with. I tried with the below approach but not working. Can any one suggest the best approach to achieve this?

```
 void openGetxBottomSheet({FocusNode? focusNode, required Widget view ,bool isDismissible = true , bool enableDrag = true, bool isScrollControlled = false}) {
    Get.bottomSheet(view, isDismissible: isDismissible, enableDrag: enableDrag, isScrollControlled: isScrollControlled).whenComplete(() {
     Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4), () {
        focusNode?.requestFocus();
      });
    });
  }
```

Below is the custom TextField,

```
FocusNode selectBoxFocusNode = FocusNode();

CustomTextField(
                focusNode: selectBoxFocusNode,
                heading: "Amount",
                maxLength: 16,
                showDropDown: true,
                showCursor: false,
                readOnly: true,
                controller: TextEditingController(text: ""),
                onTap: () {
                  openGetxBottomSheet(
                      focusNode: selectBoxFocusNode,
                      view: "Sample data"
                      isScrollControlled: true,
                  );
                  setState(() {
                   
                  });
                },
              ),
```